# Workaround for IE 1083 characters address bar limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, web

I'm having problems with large url in a web system (larger than 1083 chars).

The url is generated by one big form with get method used to filter some data displayed as a paged grid (using .net WebGrid).

If the user try share the link in address bar copying from IE, the url would be truncated in 1083 characters.

Since this form is used to search use it with POST method would be the last option since the pagination would be "wierd".

Is there any workaround for IE?

Comment: 1083 is a lot... that's over 1kb, just in URL.  I would suggest you find another way.

Comment: Sounds very much like you have to rethink your solution. How about generating your own "tiny url" for the user to share, perhaps nothing more than "mywebsite.com/mypage?searchId=unqiueintegerorguid", then just query a sql table where you save the recent search queries by the searchId reocrd. Even if this is for internal use only, it is still quite an error prone solution to make users copy and paste a massive url just to share their search query with another.